# BizTalk Deployment Issue

Tags: biztalk

I try to deploy a demo BizTalk project by using deploy menu in Visual Studio 2013.
The visual studio output window shows it has successfully deployed:

2>    : Installed the "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\BT\PID4904\BizTalkAssembly\7afb324ca64bf52f71046b867c49fa50\MyFirstBizTalkSoluntion.dll" assembly into the Global Assembly Cache. (force=True)
2>
2>    : Deploy operation succeeded.

I could not found this demo project assembly in c:\windows\assembly, but it located in
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, is there a problem?  What you posted is the expected behavior.  Deployed assemblies are GAC'd.

.Net 2.x GAC: C:\Windows\Assembly

.Net 4.x GAC: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL folder

BizTalk Projects have been .Net 4.x based since BizTalk Server 2010.